# CSRF token passing breaks my django view

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

When passing the X-CSRFToken header or sending csrfmiddlewaretoken in the POST data to my view, it completely skips the ajax handler and goes directly to the index/base view.

**Javascript:**

```
$.post("/action/register", {
          name: $('#input_name').val(),
          email: $('#input_email').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'

        }, function(data) {
          var response;
          try {
            response = JSON.parse(data.toString());  
          } catch(e) {
            response = {"status":"error", "message":"Please try again later, we're having some tech issues!"};
          }

          // ... process some stuff, the callback works which is good
```

**View:**

```
def handle_register(req):
    ''' Request handler pyfor registration, should return JSON for the AJAX request. '''

    if req.is_ajax():
        return validate_and_register(req)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('{"status":"error","message":"Invalid request."}')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^action/register$', 'views.handle_register', name='handle_register'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^.*$', 'views.handle_home', name='handle_home'),
)
```

When I don't pass the header, i get a 403 (CSRF_VERIFICATION_FAILED). When I pass the appropriate header (confirmed in multiple browsers) it skips the /action/register handler and goes directly to the "handle_home" view.

I'm stuck!

Comment: Also, /admin/ doesn't work either, it simply loads the handle_home view.

Answer (score 0):

This could possible be due to a missing slash on your url

> /action/register

Try adding a slash in url and in your javascript.

Another guess would be:

> 'views.handle_register'

is missing an app name?

A more safe was as well would be to use reverse urls:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('appname.views.handle_register')

$.post(url, {}, func...
```

Comment: The issue was related to my nginx configuration. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with nginx. Per the django/nginx setup docs I found I was missing this in my nginx config:

```
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
```

Comment: Hi @Kyle,
where did you put this line in the nginx config?